# Firebase check if item is not in array in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check in my Flutter app if an item is not in an array. If it is in it I want to sort it out, if not I want to take it.

There is an `arrayContains` function for the reverse function, but I couldn't find an `arrayContainsNot` function or something. How can I solve this?

I want to do it like this:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("someCollection")
    .where("someArray", arrayContainsNot: "someItem")
    .get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [not-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) operator.

> A not-in query returns documents where the given field exists, is not
> null, and does not match any of the comparison values.

So your code becomes:

```dart
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("someCollection")
        .where("someArray", whereNotIn: ["someItem"])
        .get();
```

Note that it supports up to 10 comparison values which have to be passed in a list to the `whereNotIn` property.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question... this could only check if the whole array is not equal, and doesn't check for individual elements of that array. So it would include the array `["someItem", "someOtherItem"]` using the query above because `["someItem", "someOtherItem"] != "someItem"`, which is not the desired behavior.