# Check if item is not in a Firebase document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field in my Firestore documents that happens to be an array of user IDs, this field is called "tempID", I want to run a query that return all documents that do not contain a particular user ID stored in "tempID". I did my research and found two useful articles.

[Firebase check if item is not in array in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037545/firebase-check-if-item-is-not-in-array-in-flutter)
I tried what was suggested in this link but I am not getting desired outcome.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_8
I read official documentation from this link but still have not been able to implement desired outcome.

Comment: Could you post your code? It is difficult to debug what we can't see.

Comment: Without seeing the code, my first thought is that you could isolate the list of user IDs, then you can check if `!list.contains(userID)`. If it doesn't contain the userID, add the result to a new list to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.